Screen recorder not properly recording on Ubuntu 22.04
This is not the same as the questions posted about an empty recording or about the recording app crashing.

I'm trying the default screen recorder, the one that pops up when hitting PrtScn. It does record the video as long as requested, but the resulting video is horizontally skewed to about 20% of the real bounding box marked for each recording, as well as the colors are black and white or way off.
Is that a typical issue? Is there a solution for this?
I have proper screen sharing working for web video calls and OBS is working properly.
Using Wayland. This is an upgraded system.
Is there any component to uninstall, re-install or upgrade, to try to solve this?

Does the issue appear in X.Org? If so, just stick to X.Org. In older versions of Ubuntu, Wayland was not mature enough for everything.

I can't switch to X.Org for just one feature. As a 30 years old technology, X.Org has several shortcomings compared to Wayland, and in addition, it will destabilize the machine as a develoment machine. I might assume that if video calls screen sharing was solved, then maybe this is solved as well in Wayland somehow.

Try it in 24.04 (fresh install instead of upgrade). First try it in a live environment (before installing) to ensure that it works.

X.Org has several shortcomings compared to Wayland What exactly was the issue with X.Org?

Thanks for commenting but it would be nice to be kindly getting solutions to the issue at hand @ArchismanPanigrahi

The solution is to either stick to X.Org, where almost everything works, or upgrade to latest version of Wayland which has less bugs (in 24.04). There is no other solution. Just because X.Org is old does not mean it is buggy. If you find some bug, let us know, we might be able to provide a workaround.
